# Instalando composer y me da problemas de permiso denegado en el mac catalina

Tags: macos, composer, terminal

tengo un problemas a instalar composer en mac catalina y me dice permision denegado, he entrado en la pagina de composer y en apartado de mac linux he seguido todo los paso pero en la parte de crear la carpeta:

> Nota: en algunas versiones de macOS, el /usrdirectorio no existe de forma predeterminada. Si recibe el error "/ usr / local / bin / compositor locales: No existe el fichero o directorio", entonces debe crear el directorio de forma manual antes de proceder: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin.

Ha procesar `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin.` me sale en el terminal

```
mkdir: /usr/local/bin.: Permission denied
```

Ha pasar esto  no me deja crear la carpeta para mover el composer phar y tener de forma global. 
Que solución se darias  gracias .

---

posiblemente será el fallo de punto que he puesto mkdir -p /usr/local/bin 
de toda manera sigo teniendo el un fallo mirando un tutorial que vi en youtube que bueno  [para ver el video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXV7XGiDvLs&feature=youtu.be) 
 y me sale el problemas este

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied
```

que solución podría soy un poco nuevo en el mac

Comment: posiblemente será el fallo de punto que he puesto mkdir -p /usr/local/bin de toda manera sigo teniendo el un fallo mirando un tutorial que vi en youtube que bueno [para ver el video ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXV7XGiDvLs&feature=youtu.be) y me sale el problemas este mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied que solución podría soy un poco nuevo en el mac

Comment: Has probado con `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`? Aunque me parece extraño que te pida crear ese directorio... Quizás podrías seguir alguna otra forma de instalación, por ejemplo usando brew

Comment: lo he probado usando sudo  y funciona correctamente gracias